# How to switch back to Unity

Tags: unity, screen, cairo

I have a very big problem. I just installed **cairo-dock** and I logged out from my Unity.

As I logged out, Ubuntu showed me options to select other desktop, I saw an option of Cairo Desktop and I chose it and logged in. But since I logged in, it just shows me a black screen.

I don't be able to do anything! I do not see anything on the screen, can't even open terminal. Keyboard has stopped working and mouse pointer is not visible!

There is no option to logout. I'm in a big trouble. When I press power key of my laptop, it shuts down but when I start it again, it shows me black screen only.

I want to switch to Unity environment back. Is there any option? I don't want to format my computer.

I use Ubuntu-14.04.1.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open a TTY by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login with your username and password. Restart LightDM by typing:

> sudo service lightdm restart

You should get in the login screen, where you have to choose Unity. When logged in with Unity session, you can use the terminal or return to the tty and delete the package by using:

> sudo apt-get remove --purge cairo-dock

Comment: My keyboard has stopped working!! And Im quitting ubuntu. Windows with viruses is lot better than ubuntu with bugs.

Comment: You can execute the commands from recovery mode and you should report a bug at Launchpad. When you get a buggy package or your computer isn't powerful enough you may have problems

Comment: You could also purge cairo-dock *before* restarting lightdm.

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. login and password
3. sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock
4. sudo reboot

Comment: My keyboard has stopped working!! And Im quitting ubuntu. Windows with viruses is lot better than ubuntu with bugs.